# Advanced Pandas: Create Multi-Index panda dataframe from certain row indices

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data set like this:

```
    m   n   o  
0   2   22  42  
1   3   23  43  
2   4   24  44  
3   5   25  45  
4   6   26  46  
5   7   27  47  
6   8   28  48  
7   9   29  49  
8   10  30  50  
9   11  31  51
```

How can we convert this into multi-index dataframe:

```
Index   m    n  o  
  A  
     0  2   22  42  
     1  3   23  43  
     2  4   24  44  
  B  
    4   6   26  46  
  C  
    6   8   28  48  
    7   9   29  49  
    8   10  30  50
```

** My attempt**

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'m': np.arange(2,12),
                   'n': np.arange(22,32),
                  'o': np.arange(42,52)})

df
```

** The groupby method**

```
# Required index and their names
idx = [3,5,9]  # A is 0,1,2 B is 4 and C is 6,7,8
idx_orig = idx.copy()
idx_names = ['A','B','C']

# Attempt
idx_diff = np.diff(idx)
idx_diff = np.hstack((idx[0]+1,idx_diff)) # Add the first index value
idx_diff = idx_diff - 1 # Decrease index number
idx_names = np.repeat(idx_names,idx_diff)

# Drop rows with given indices
df = df.drop(df.index[idx_orig])

# Assign new col
df['Names'] = idx_names
#df.groupby('Names').count()
df
```

**The output**

```
    m   n   o   Names
0   2   22  42  A
1   3   23  43  A
2   4   24  44  A
4   6   26  46  B
6   8   28  48  C
7   9   29  49  C
8   10  30  50  C
```

Here, I wanted to get a multi-index dataframe with all the rows, however, groupby gives only the counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
idx = [3,5,9] 

idx_names = ['A','B','C']
d = dict(enumerate(idx_names))

#get boolean mask for create cumulative sum and filter out idx rows
mask = df.index.isin(idx)
df['g'] = mask.cumsum()
#map by dictioanry
df['g'] = df['g'].map(d)
#create MultiIndex and change order of levels
df = df[~mask].set_index('g', append=True).swaplevel(0,1)
print (df)
      m   n   o
g              
A 0   2  22  42
  1   3  23  43
  2   4  24  44
B 4   6  26  46
C 6   8  28  48
  7   9  29  49
  8  10  30  50
```

Comment: How to get values for just 'A' like df['A'] ?

Comment: @astro123 - Use `df.loc['A']`

Comment: Or `print (df.xs('A'))` - [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

Comment: Which is better   `.loc` or `.xs` ? Is `.xs` deprecated ?

Comment: @astro123 - No, it is `ix`  - [`ix-indexer-is-deprecated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated)